# How can I create a mailTo link whos body contains a link containing escape values

Tags: javascript, html, email, mailto

I have an api who expects the format:

`/api/download/file%20name/file%2fpath`

See the `spaces` and `\` are escaped as `%20` and `%2f`

When I create a maitTo link:

```
mailto:?subject=file%20name&body="example.com/api/download/file%20name/file%2fpath
```

the client (My requirement is outlook only) escapes these values when it creates the email replacing the escaped values in the url with true spaces and slashes, therefore invalidating the url.

End up with this `example.com/api/download/file name/file/path` as the body

Is there anyway to prevent this by encoding the mailto differently? I don't have a way to edit the apis format at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to pass values in a url.

```
var url = 'mailto:'+
    '?subject='+encodeURIComponent('file name')+
    '&body='+encodeURIComponent('example.com/api/download/file name/file/path')
```

Comment: Clever! That was the same command I was using to encode the URL's. Guess it is working because I'm encoding them twice. thanks